# How to create nested dictionaries with duplicate keys in python

Tags: python, dictionary, autovivification

I want to create data structure with nested dictionaries and duplicate keys. A detailed example is:

```
data['State1']['Landon']['abc Area'] = 'BOB'
data['State1']['Landon']['abc Area'] = 'SAM'
data['State1']['Landon']['xyz Area'] = 'John'
data['State2']['New York']['hjk Area'] = 'Ricky'

for z in data['State1'].keys() , 
# I should get list ['Landon', 'Landon', 'Landon']
for y in data['State1']['Landon'].keys() , 
# I should get list ['abc Area', 'abc Area', 'xyz Area']
```

Currently to store the data I have used extra counter key

```
data = Autovivification()  
data[state][city][area][counter] = ID
```

But while parsing total entries (duplicates as well) of City/Area, I have to use nested loops till counter key.

```
for city in data['State1'].keys():
  for area in data['State1'][city].keys():
    for counter in data['State1'][city][area].keys():
     for temp in data['State1'][city][area][counter].values():
         cityList.append(city)
         areaList.append(area)
```

For nested dictionaries, I found the following code posted by nosklo

```
class AutoVivification(dict):  
    """Implementation of perl's autovivification feature."""  
    def __getitem__(self, item):                
         try:  
            return dict.__getitem__(self, item)  
        except KeyError:   
            value = self[item] = type(self)()  
            return value
```

and for dictionary with duplicate keys, I found code posted by Scorpil

```
class Dictlist(dict):  
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):  
        try:   
            self[key]   
        except KeyError:   
            super(Dictlist, self).__setitem__(key, [])   
        self[key].append(value)
```

how to merge Autovivification and Duplicate class code? or is there any other pythonic way to handle such scenario?

Comment: Can you explain, why do you need duplicate keys? Is it ok if 'Area' will be list, where you can add multiple ID?

Comment: @germn : I have edited the question with more explanation , can you please check

Comment: I updated answer adding new `items_in` function that would return list you need for given data. I'm sure it would be easier and clearer to implement functions to work with dict/list structure, then trying to implement your new structure.

Comment: @GerasimovMikhail   Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One more example using [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html):

```
from collections import defaultdict


data = defaultdict(  # State
    lambda: defaultdict(  # City
        lambda: defaultdict(list)  # Area
    )
)


data['State']['City']['Area'].append('area 1')
data['State']['City']['Area'].append('area 2')
data['State']['City']['Area'].append('area 2')


areas = data['State']['City']['Area']
print(areas)  # ['area 1', 'area 2', 'area 2']

total = len(areas)
print(total)  # 3
```

How to get list of items you want, using this solution:

```
data['State1']['Landon']['abc Area'].append('BOB')
data['State1']['Landon']['abc Area'].append('SAM')
data['State1']['Landon']['xyz Area'].append('John')
data['State2']['New York']['hjk Area'].append('Ricky')


def items_in(d):
    res = []
    if isinstance(d, list):
        res.extend(d)
    elif isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            res.extend([k] * len(items_in(v)))
    else:
        raise ValueError('Unknown data')
    return res


print(items_in(data['State1']))  # ['Landon', 'Landon', 'Landon']
print(items_in(data['State1']['Landon']))  # ['xyz Area', 'abc Area', 'abc Area']
print(items_in(data['State1']['Landon']['abc Area']))  # ['BOB', 'SAM']
print(items_in(data['State1']['Landon']['xyz Area']))  # ['John']

print(items_in(data['State2']))  # ['New York']
print(items_in(data['State2']['New York']))  # ['hjk Area']
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple way would be to make it a list and then just add every new key to the list:

```
Data['State']['City']['Area'] = []
Data['State']['City']['Area'].append( ID )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the `AutoVivication` class with one that auto-vivificates `Dictlists` instead of `dicts`:

```
class AutoVivificationDL(Dictlist):  
    """Implementation of perl's autovivification feature."""  
    def __getitem__(self, item):                
         try:  
            return dict.__getitem__(self, item)  
        except KeyError:   
            value = self[item] = type(self)()  
            return value
```

Comment: Thanks,  I have edited the question with more explanation , can you please check ? , when I used your code 'RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object ' is observed.

Comment: Hm, hadn't thought of that. I think this is Python telling you that this whole AutoVivification thing is not Pythonic :) You're probably better off using a combination of `defaultdict` and regular lists instead of "duplicate entries". If you haven't done so yet, you might also try to reconsider whether you need such a super-flexible datastructure at all, or whether you know enough about your data in advance to just build a nested dict with a predetermined depth.

Answer (score 0):

```
Data = {}


values = [
    dict(State="CA", City="San Francisco", Area="North", Id="customer1"),
    dict(State="CA", City="San Francisco", Area="Embarcadero", Id="customer1"),
    dict(State="CA", City="San Francisco", Area="North", Id="customer2"),

]

for v in values:
    #grab the existing entry.  if it doesn't exist, returns a list
    li = Data.setdefault((v["State"],v["City"],v["Area"]),[])
    li.append(v["Id"])

print "Data:%s" % (Data)
```

output:

```
Data:{('CA', 'San Francisco', 'North'): ['customer1', 'customer2'], ('CA', 'San Francisco', 'Embarcadero'): ['customer1']}
```

You're not limited to a very simple Id value, you can add pretty much anything you want to the list.  If you expect to be doing this at a number of spots,look into https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict, which kinda does a built-in setdefault.

In fact, you could add IDs to a dictionary instead of a list, it's all the same.